# Add elements (obstacles, walls, etc.) in a URDF file

Tags: gazebo, urdf, ros-lunar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've just started to learn how to implement an URDF. To do it, I'm following the [tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials) about URDF in ROS Wiki.

But, those tutorials only talk about how to define a robot, but If I want to add obstacles or walls to show them in Gazebo. How can I do it?

Maybe I can add those things inside the world definition.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/304070/add-elements-(obstacles,-walls,-etc.)-in-a-urdf-file/) by [Elric](https://answers.ros.org/users/30817/elric/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2018-09-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use the exact same primitive geometry elements `box`, `cylinder` and `sphere`to define obstacles.

A flat box is a wall fi.

Then use a `fixed` joint to attach them to your world.

Although if you're going for Gazebo, then using SDF might be better.

Treat Gazebo as providing you "virtual hardware". Use RViz to visualise your robot's sensor data. Not the world directly.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-09-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Elric](https://answers.ros.org/users/30817/elric/) on 2018-09-24**:
Thanks. Do I have to put them inside the robot tag?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-09-24**:
Yes.

The `robot` tag is not special, it's just the root of the file.

You can model entire worlds "in" it.